# systemd run unit on success of another

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I converted some cron jobs to [systemd.timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#) units and want to send a mail on each job failure *and* success.

The excellent [ArchLinux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#As_a_cron_replacement) provides information about this and the setup runs smoothly on failure. Now I want to add an email notification whenever the unit ran successful, but according to [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#) there is no configuration named *OnSuccess=*.

How to handle this use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `ExecStartPost=/bin/systemctl start some-other-service` if the `Type=` is `oneshot`.

Read about the details in `man systemd.service`

To review a full list of directions, use `man systemd.directives`, which lists all the directions and where they are documented.

Comment: Currently I go with `Type=simple`, but I might migrate to `oneshot` without problem. Nice catch that `ExecStartPost=` fires after successful *termination* if the `Type=` is set accordingly.

Comment: PLEASE, abstain from controlling other services explicitely from unit scripts like seen here.  This might create endless activating/deactivating service loop hells.  Instead, try to use SystemD to express this.  Example:  In `this.service` use `Wants: other.service` and in  `other.service` use `Requisite: this.service` and `After: this.service`.  So `other.service` starts after `this.service` only if `this.service` does not fail.  (I am not sure, but documentation seems to say that.)

Comment: @Tino  Wants= and After= are only about *starting services at boot*. This question was about running other services when *run* (possibly after boot). There is no need for  the approach to cause a loop. Like everything else, you should test it to see if it works.